# usb external backup hard drive

Tags: usb-drive

I have a Microsoft Windows 7 OS. I use a WD USB backup external hard drive. I want backup this drive to my other PC running Ubuntu 14.04. Is there some way I can restore this data to my Ubuntu PC. Also, if this is accomplished, is there a way to format my WD hard drive with Ubuntu OS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the Windows 7 backup tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. For that you need to mount this external drive to Ubuntu(i am assuming your trying to do this in Ubuntu)

```
sudo mkdir /media/external
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/external -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

or

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external
```

choose based on your format type.

For more info, visit [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB)